# Spring boot failed to start

Tags: linux, webserver, centos-7

I have a error and I tried to figure out what was wrong for 2 hours and I can't fix it.

I ran my spring boot app using java -jar command, it's a package and it couldn't start.

I set the properties file to set the port for 80 and my firewalld is disabled and I ran on centos7 machine. and I tried netstat command and there was no service for port 80 so it is not a port problem i think.

This is error log:

```
2019-01-21 16:02:56.183  INFO 8158 --- [           main] com.springboot.PjsSpringBootApplication  : Starting PjsSpringBootApplication v1.0 on carpfishncptest1 with PID 8158 (/home/jh31/pjs-spring-boot/target/pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar started by jh31 in /home/jh31/pjs-spring-boot/target)
2019-01-21 16:02:56.186  INFO 8158 --- [           main] com.springboot.PjsSpringBootApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-21 16:02:57.702  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2019-01-21 16:02:57.729  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-21 16:02:57.730  INFO 8158 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-21 16:02:57.740  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-01-21 16:02:57.812  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-21 16:02:57.813  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1571 ms
2019-01-21 16:02:58.056  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-21 16:02:58.174  WARN 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.MustacheAutoConfiguration      : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
2019-01-21 16:02:58.192  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2019-01-21 16:02:58.277 ERROR 8158 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1004) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.springboot.PjsSpringBootApplication.main(PjsSpringBootApplication.java:10) [classes!/:1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1085) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:568) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        ... 22 common frames omitted

2019-01-21 16:02:58.282  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-01-21 16:02:58.292  INFO 8158 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-21 16:02:58.293 ERROR 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 80, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-01-21 16:02:58.296  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: What is says in the message: you already have something using port 80 (another instance of the server?) (check with `netstat -lt` and look for `80` or `http`) or your port 80 is disabled by a firewall.

Comment: thank you for the comment, but I already tried netstat and there was no httpd and port 80 is free to use. no service in the port

Answer (score 2):

Ports below 1024 are restricted to root user only. Try running your jar as root.

If you run your app on, let's say, Tomcat, then Tomcat needs root privileges to open port 80.